# List fields present in a table

Tags: python, django

Is there any way to to list out the fields present in a table in django models

```
 class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(School)
    emp = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

How to list out the filed names from the table Profile,(just like desc Profile; in mysql )

thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Profile._meta.fields` will get you a list of fields. The `name` property of the field object contains the name of the field. `Profile._meta.get_fields_with_model()` will return a list of 2-tuples of `(field, model)`, with `model` being `None` if the field is in `Profile`.