# Search multiple fields of django model without 3rd party app

Tags: django, search, django-models

I have a single model in my django app that I want to create a search form for. Is there a way to search all the fields in the model at once with the same search string? I've looked into xapian and solr but they seem like a lot of overhead for searching over 1 model. I want to be able to say something like:

```
results = Assignment.objects.filter(any_column = search_string)
```

I realize there might not be something that concise but right now the only option I can come up with other than using a search app is to check each field separately and concatenate the results together.

Comment: `reduce()` with `operator.or_` and `Q` objects and kwarg expansion.

Comment: Could you show a simple example maybe with 2 fields? I tried looking for the reduce() function in the django docs and I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Once you have all the [field names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2368948/20862) you can create [`Q` objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) using [kwarg expansion](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) and use [`reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce) along with [`operator.or_`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.or_) to turn them into a single query.

```
qgroup = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(**{fieldname: value}) for fieldname in fieldnames))
asgns = Assignment.objects.filter(qgroup)
```

Comment: I had to add parenthesis around the Q(...) objects but otherwise this worked like a charm! Thank you. Is there a reason why something like this isn't made into a shortcut in django. You would think for searching simple models like this having syntax like my initial example would be a great tool right?

Comment: Dunno. Probably because it's trivial to do with Python.

Comment: So you would say that `qgroup = reduce(operator.or_, Q(**{fieldname: value}) for fieldname in fieldnames)` would be trivial for a django programmer versus having `Assignment.objects.filter(any_column='somestring')` being part of the API ? Interesting... I know it may not be trivial to implement on the django side but I just think it would be a common usage for searching models.

Comment: It would be trivial for a Python programmer. And not something a Django programmer would need often.

Comment: It may be trivial to do with python, but sql is waay faster

Comment: @danbgray: The ORM is manipulated in Python, but it generates SQL regardless.

Comment: In Python 3.x reduce was moved from the built-in functions to the functools module

Comment: This generated repeated results for me. This way, if the value/term appears in different fields, the query returns the same object many times (once per field). How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for further reference I am adding this:

In django 1.10 [SearchVector](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchvector) class was added.

Usage from the docs:

> Searching against a single field is great but rather limiting. The Entry instances we’re searching belong to a Blog, which has a tagline field. To query against both fields, use a SearchVector:

```
>>> from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
>>> Entry.objects.annotate(
...     search=SearchVector('body_text', 'blog__tagline'),
... ).filter(search='Cheese')
[<Entry: Cheese on Toast recipes>, <Entry: Pizza Recipes>]
```