# How to make a generic variable in a query

Tags: django

I have this query:

```
search = request.GET['q']
Entries = Entry.objects.filter(Q(field1__icontains=search), Q(field2__icontains=search), Q(field3__icontains=search))
```

Is there an elegant way to make this cleaner? (I mean make somthing generic like `Q(var_field__icontains=search)` and the `var_field` will be retrived from a requested post that is one of these values field1, field2, field3).

Comment: @rednaw https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: I think it looks pretty ok as it is now. You may try this method though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487054/search-multiple-fields-of-django-model-without-3rd-party-app

Comment: @matino If the number of `Q` objects is fixed, don't bother with `reduce`, it would only clutter your code. Simply use `or` or `and` directly to combine the three `Q`s.

Comment: In Python 3.x reduce was moved from the standard built-in functions to the functools module.

Comment: @matino: +1 (for the useful link)

Answer (score 0):

So, is this working for you?

```
search = request.GET['q']
fieldnames = ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')

filters = reduce(operator.and_, 
    (Q(**{'{}__icontains'.format(fieldname): search}) 
     for fieldname in fieldnames))

Entries = Entry.objects.filter(filters)
```