# how do i loop through fields of an object?

Tags: python, django, model

I have a model like this, how can I loop through it and not have to type out company.id, company.name, etc?

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    zip = models.IntegerField()
    state = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Comment: To do what? Assign to them? Use them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - Iterate over model instance field names and values in template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170228/django-iterate-over-model-instance-field-names-and-values-in-template)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First [get them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368948/list-fields-present-in-a-table), then use a for loop or list comprehension.

Answer (score 26):

You can loop over all field names like so

```
for name in Company._meta.get_all_field_names():
    print name
```

this also works if you have a category instance:

```
c = Company(name="foo",website="bar",email="baz@qux.com",....,)
c.save()
for field in c._meta.get_all_field_names():
    print getattr(c, field, None)
```

**Update for Django 1.8**

Django 1.8 now has an [official model Meta api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model) and you can easily grab all the fields:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
for field in User._meta.get_fields():
    print field
```

Answer (score 7):

Iteration in a **view**:

If you have an instance `company` of `Company`:

```
fields= company.__dict__
for field, value in fields.items():
    print field, value
```

Comment: Excellent! How would I remove specific tuples from the dict_items list that `__dict__.items()` generates?

Comment: the dict contains "internal only" fields, such as `_state`

Answer (score 1):

this is a possible solution:

```
entity = Company.all().get()

for propname, prop in entity.properties().items():   
    print propname, prop.get_value_for_datastore(entity)
```

another one could be:

```
# this returns a dict with the property 
# name as key and the property val as its value
entity.__dict__.get('_entity')
```