# How to run a loop in python to check "Required" column in MSAccess (.mdb)

Tags: python, ms-access, tkinter, pyodbc

I'm working in python coding to automate the new queries base on exiting table in .mdb files.
I would like to ask about how to run a loop to check whether the "Required" co to yes or no (In the current checking table). I will use the setting for next step to generate the SQL command in python.

Remark: In Microsoft website use command
"CREATE INDEX index_name ON table (field) WITH DISALLOW NULL"
to create this kind of column
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/require-a-value-in-a-field-d6bf6ff6-d653-48ef-b484-54a33c36f6c6

[image: In MSAccess is use the setting "required"]

Comment: You want to change the Required property of existing field? I tested this SQL and it creates an index on specified field but the Required property is unchanged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do i loop through fields of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353804/how-do-i-loop-through-fields-of-an-object)

Comment: In VBA / MS-Access the `TableDef.Fields` property contains all the columns of the table.
The `Dao.Field` has a `Required` Property. You now just have to call these functions via COM or some Libary.

Comment: What does this have to do with tkinter? You've shown no code with tkinter functions, and the actual question doesn't mention tkinter.